# GCC and Clang don't compile std::hash<std::nullptr_t> in C++17

Tags: c++, gcc, hash, clang, c++17

On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash it says that since C++17

> Each standard library header that declares the template std::hash
>   provides enabled specializations of std::hash for std::nullptr_t and
>   all cv-unqualified arithmetic types (including any extended integer
>   types), all enumeration types, and all pointer types.

So, a C++17 compliant compiler should compile this little program:

```
#include <functional>
int main()
{
    std::hash<std::nullptr_t> h;
    return h(nullptr);
}
```

However, GCC and Clang both are reporting an error saying that the default constructor of `std::hash<std::nullptr_t>` is (implicitly) deleted.
See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/JVDcqc) and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/yYDyo_) to verify it yourself.

[Visual Studio](https://godbolt.org/z/_rn0xT) does compile it. Apparently it returns <s>`0`</s> `672807365`.

**Q1:** Are GCC and Clang simply still missing this C++17 feature, as admittedly this is not a high priority one? Or am I missing something?

**Q2:** Can I just specialize it myself and return <s>`0`</s> `672807365` like Visual Studio? <s>Wouldn't some other value, e.g. some prime, be better for combining it with other hashes?</s>

---

### Update

Due to my limited assembler knowledge I thought that Visual Studio is returning `0`. In fact, it is returning `672807365` (the value in `eax`).
So, my second question basically answers itself: I will *not* return `0` in my specialization to workaround this bug.

Comment: sorry, rolled back my edit. The typo is in the source...

Comment: @user463035818 np, I stumbled over that one, too.

Comment: @user463035818 cppreference is a wiki. Better than rollbacking you could have corrected that page. I've just done that, you can rollback your rollback.

Comment: @YSC actually I didnt know and I dont have an account there. rolled forward my edit ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Neither do I ;)

Comment: @YSC haha i just checked again and realized that there is a big fat `Edit` button. I guess I got so much used to it that at some point I started ignoring it. Next time I'll know

Comment: Works on clang HEAD, returning 156. https://wandbox.org/permlink/tu1WxRoqhGwv6Cm7

Comment: Bug in libstdc++? libc++ is fine (use -stdlib=libc++)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Is this program correct?

cppreference.com is right. From the latest C++ Standard draft:

> ### [`[unord.hash]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.hash#2.sentence-3)
>
> Each specialization of hash is either enabled or disabled, as described below. [...] Each header that declares the template hash provides enabled specializations of `hash` for `nullptr_­t` and all cv-unqualified arithmetic, enumeration, and pointer types.

Since `<functional>` declares the `hash` template<sup>1</sup>, it must provide an enabled specialization for `std::hash<std::nullptr_t>`. **Your example program should be accepted by any conforming C++17 implementation**.

---

### Why it is not though?

C++17 being still young, some subtle features might be missing still or buggy on recent compilers. Be reassured, your MCVE is accepted by gcc and clang in their development/[experimental](https://godbolt.org/z/YSWO-z) branches.

We couldn't find a development version of GCC accepting it though; this is why **a bug report has been raised by [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) (see [std::hashstd::nullptr_t](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88802) not implemented) and fixed by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely)** (see [revision267845](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=267845)) (and it [returns zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blobdiff;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/functional_hash.h;h=32dc00c5a6f90f720918d6063be8c2aad762a7b3;hp=2245fad69a791a01fa359cafcfd57d6fd9b7cb77;hb=17a73b3c47f58155350af2e1ca359e915ffedcae;hpb=d58cb9659f8edd691f2c3f5595b6ac258eec58b9)).

---

### How to fix your program while you're waiting for your implementation to get fixed?

> Can I just specialize it myself and return 0 like Visual Studio?

You would be writing code that will exhibit Undefined Behavior<sup>2</sup>. Do it at your own risk. Document it well. For instance, put the following in a *separate* translation unit:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(
    false == std::is_default_constructible_v<std::hash<std::nullptr_t>>,
    "Explanation"
);
```

This will warn your colleagues and ask them to manually remove your specialization of `std::hash<std::nullptr_t>` rather than get them a nasty compilation error.

---

<sup>1)</sup> See [`[functional.syn]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/functional.syn).

<sup>2)</sup> You are [only allowed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) to specialize `std` class templates for program-defined types (which `nullptr_­t` isn't). You could also break the One Definition Rule.